# android: listview long click & context popup causing stackoverflowerror (possibly due to actionbarsherlock?)

Tags: android, listview, actionbarsherlock, onlongclicklistener

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is happening.
I've looked through the ABS sample code (which works fine for non-listviews), I've searched online and followed instructions correctly, but still I have some strange bug.

During my onCreate() I call this code:

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        registerForContextMenu(view);
        openContextMenu(view);
        return true;
    }
});
```

When long clicking the item, for some reason it keeps going from:

- (line 6) `openContextMenu()`
- `View.showContextMenu()`
- `AbsListView.showContextMenuForChild()`
- back to (line 6) `openContextMenu()`

I do have a click listener set, but it shouldn't be affecting anything as it opens a new activity if clicked.

For completeness, here's the context menu creation.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.lvFines) {
        menu.add("One");
        menu.add("Two");
        menu.add("Three");
        menu.add("Four");
    }
}
```

Am I using the wrong "support" function from ActionBarSherlock?